# WIX Change Initial install directory

Tags: wix, installation

When I make my WIX Build setup,

by default it installs into the ProgramFIles directory.

I want to change this to the Application Local Data directory,

How would I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use folder definitions like this:

```
<Directory Id='LocalAppDataFolder'>
    <Directory Id='MyAppFolder' Name='MyApp' />
</Directory>
```

To find the IDs of other system folders like `LocalAppDataFolder`, take a look at the [System Folder Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370905%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#system_folder_properties) section of the [Windows Installer Property reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370905%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing a per-user installation using the built in dialog sets?

If you set `Package/@InstallScope="perUser"` then the default installation folder will automatically be set to `[LocalAppDataFolder]Apps\[ApplicationFolderName]`

For more information [refer to the WiX manual.](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_package.htm)